# How to convert XML to Byte to File/PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wpf, asp.net-core

I have successfully done "find and replace" which created an xml. Now I want to convert the newly created xml file to pdf which will be attached as a file and sent in a mail.

The result of the Base64String was tested on a base64 pdf file converter but the pdf cannot be opened. Got this error: **Something went wrong couldn't open the file**

HOW CAN I MAKE THIS WORK?

```
        public async Task<string> CreateDocument(string PolicyNumber)
        {
            var policy = await _context.Policy.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PolicyNumber == PolicyNumber);

            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(policy, "Policy Not Available");
            //CreatePolicyDocument

            //create policy document
            var files = @"C:\Users\PATHTODOCUMENT\holderTest.docx";

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(files, true))
            {

                string docText;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Regex regexText = new Regex("XCONCLUSION_DATEX");
                var newWordText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(newWordText);


                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    byte[] docAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(newWordText);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("hello.pdf", docAsBytes);
                    var file = Convert.ToBase64String(docAsBytes);
                 
                }


            }

            //send message
            //
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: The problem may be in sending the data and not the conversion.  To putting in the code above code that take file and converts back to pdf.  So you would need to use encoding.GetString(byte[]).  The n try opening file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF file has its own construct,so you can't generate a pdf file with the contentstring of xml file  dirctly.

If you really want to convert xml contentstring to PDF,you could try iTextSharp.
[image]

I tried with a simple demo,and here's the code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult XMLtoPDF([FromForm] Try T1)
        {            
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(T1.file.OpenReadStream());
            var filestring = streamContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outputStream);
            //PDF settings
            PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, doc.PageSize.Height, 1f);            
            doc.Open();            
            var paragraph = new Paragraph(filestring);
            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            var pdfArray = outputStream.ToArray();          
            return File(pdfArray, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Result:
[image]